# I have forgotten how to read the quran. Where can I learn to read Arabic?

Tags: quran, arabic

Assalamu aliakum. I am 12 years old. I learned to recite the Quran when I was very young. But a few years back  I stopped reciting quran and now I don't know how to read Arabic, I have forgotten. I don't want to tell my parents because I am ashamed and also they will be angry with me. Is there a website where I can learn to read Arabic for free?

Please help

Jazakallahu Khair

Comment: The easiest way to find one is at http://www.youtube.com itself. There are tons of videos which you can learn the quran and reading arabic.

Comment: This series of videos by `Voyagers of Knowledge` is excellent. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGsRR5mM53k4LTKk338b1RLiFH_8S2vqm

Answer (score 0):

https://www.lqtoronto.com/tibyan.html
This book "At-Tibyan" presents a  method to learn to read the Glorious Quran.
There are also some books on tajweed so if u need them i will provide the link

Answer (score 0):

Assalam walikum warahmatulahi wabarakathahuu
U can download the app Al Quran in the playstore and read it with meaning and tasfeer..
May Allah bless us and guide us to the straight path..
Jazzakallahu khair

Answer (score 0):

Either online/app/YouTube I suggest you start with the noorania quida then let your memory kick in. Then practice reading the Quran with Quran Explorer and start to see how everything connects

Answer (score 0):

Duolingo has a free course in Arabic for English Speakers. They have an app and a website version of the course.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned reading Quran during childhood but I also nearly forgot how to read by I am an adult. I studied Arabic again using Arabic by Radio course from Egypt Radio. I think it is still available. Later on I studied Arabic language, especially classical Arabic which is the Arabic used in Quran. Now I know classic Arabic well enough I can grasp the basic meaning of most verses.

For beginners I recommend this site https://www.madinaharabic.com/ . Previously it was completely free, now I don't know the status.

You can find some resources in my answer here
https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2610/what-are-the-most-effective-ways-for-a-beginner-to-learn-arabic-for-reading-the/2920#2920